# display content below 100% height absolute div

Tags: html, css

There are many questions around this subject, but non I've found that seem to work for me. I have a header element that I set to `position:absolute; height:100%`, however, the content under this goes behind the absolute element. What's the best way to solve this issue? here's a simplified version of my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <header></header>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

things I've tried:
Making the container relative:

```
/** this still covers the div below and appears to make no difference **/
.container { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
    position: relative;
}
```

Adding margin to the content:

```
/**works for one screen-size but not responsive obviously **/
.content {
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

adding a 'filler' div

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <header></header>
    <!-- also tried putting the spacer into the header with no results -->
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.spacer {
    height:100%;
    /* also tried min-height: 100%;
}
```

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong and what I should try?

Comment: if you remove position: absolute the content will follow the header

Comment: Yeah.  I can't imagine why you would want an absolutely positioned div at 100% height _AND_ have the rest of the content beneath it.  What you're describing is just normal document flow, and as many others have said, this doesn't need to be absolutely positioned.

Comment: @JoshBurgess i wanted a 100% width + height background image, but it's parent was 80% width, so i needed it to overflow, so i set it as absolute, but yeah removing absolute, making sure html, body had `height:100%` appears to have worked

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `position` and `overflow` rules from your CSS.

---

I recommend you use the firebug plugin in Firefox. Go to internet and find the plugin and install it. It's more effective with Firefox more than Chrome or any other browsers.

After that where ever something went wrong. Just right click on that and click "inspect with firebug".
Then you can inspect or add new attributes and see the impact of each change.